# Azur IoT Edge Hub fails to start

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-edge

I have upgraded an iot edge to 1.2 and it edge hub does not start.  As per error below (truncated)

```
 --->  Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Edgelet.EdgeletCommunicationException- Message:Error calling start module edgeHub: Could not start module edgeHub  
    caused by: Could not start module edgeHub  
    caused by: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint edgeHub (8eebbec9c348b1edfbf351779caf1708b2bfea1ebdd26824695649aa42d20f63): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8883 failed: port is already allocated, StatusCode:500, at:   at 
[...].
```

There is however no processes on port 8883 as confirmed by nestat (see below)

```sh
:~ $ sudo netstat -peanut  
Active Internet connections (servers and established)  
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address        State       User       Inode      PID/Program name  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          14269      549/sshd  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          15028      449/cupsd  
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:22         192.168.1.5:53532.        ESTABLISHED 0          20255      985/sshd: pi [priv]
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:47938      20.50.65.133:443        ESTABLISHED 0          19292      521/dotnet. 
tcp6       0      0 :::5671                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          20728      962/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          14271      549/sshd  
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3350                :::*                    LISTEN      0          18647      551/xrdp-sesman  
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          15027      449/cupsd  
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          20779      976/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::3389                 :::*                    LISTEN      115        17031      573/xrdp  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40863           0.0.0.0:*                           108        15018      405/avahi-daemon: r  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           0          18975      487/dhcpcd  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           0          17860      520/cups-browsed  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           108        15016      405/avahi-daemon: r  
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                108        15017      405/avahi-daemon: r  
udp6       0      0 :::44826                :::*                                108        15019      405/avahi-daemon:  
r:~ $.
```

I have removed iotedge, moby, and it still lingers.

Comment: Quick check: are there any containers in a stopped state that are using port 8883? Running `docker container ls -a` might show an old container that needs to be removed.

Comment: nope, nothing using the port

Comment: Can you open a bug in the iotedge repo providing more details as the template suggests? Share here the link after you do it for follow-up: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/new/choose